# How to add an arrow in html5 canvas polar clock

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have made a polar clock in canvas with the help of following documentation.

[Canvas Polar Clock By HenrikJoreteg](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/Polar-Clock-Canvas/blob/master/index.html)

I have achieved what i needed, except an arrow on the tip of every circle,
like arrow in image

How could i add these arrows on every rotating circle?

```js
    function clock(){
        // get current time from client
        var now = new Date();
        
        // get 2D context from the canvas element
        var ctx = document.getElementById('clockCanvas').getContext('2d');
        
        // You'll see a save and restore all over the place. These are because we
        // are redrawing the entire image every time, so we have to save the existing
        // state of the canvas and then add our other shape and then restore what we 
        // saved.
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,800);
        ctx.translate(400,300);
        ctx.scale(2,2);
        // this rotates the canvas so that the arcs we draw will start at the middle
        // top rather than horizontally.
        ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/2);
        // sets the width of all lines we're going to draw
        ctx.lineWidth = 18;
        // gives our lines a rounded edge.
        // it also supports "butt" and "square"
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        
        // I wanted to get a smooth movement so I'm basing all time measurments off
        // of the millisecond and building partial seconds and minutes by adding the
        // smaller increment to the larger one. For example getting current millisecond
        // count and adding that to the current second to build a partial second.
        var milliSec = now.getMilliseconds();         
        var sec = now.getSeconds();
        sec = milliSec/1000+sec;
        var min = now.getMinutes();
        min = sec/60 + min;
        // this is a 24 hour clock
        var hr  = now.getHours();
        // if you uncomment the following line, it'd become a 12 hour clock.
        // hr = hr>=12 ? hr-12 : hr;
        hr = min/60 + hr;
        var dow = now.getDay() + 1;
        var day = now.getDate();
        var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
        
        // turn times into percentages
        var secPer = sec/60;
        var minPer = min/60;
        // if you wanted a 12 hour clock, you'd have to change this to 12 too.
        var hrPer = hr/24;
        var dowPer = dow/7;
        var monthPer = month/12;
        var dayPer = 0;
        
        // handles the fact that there are different amount of total days in different months
        if (month == 2){
            dayPer = day/29;
        }
        else if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12){
            dayPer = day/31;
        }
        else {
            dayPer = day/30;
        }   
        
        // call the functions that draw each arc and pass in the radius of the circle we want
        // and the calculated percentages from above.
        writeTime(ctx,40,monthPer);
        writeTime(ctx,60,dayPer);
        writeTime(ctx,80,dowPer);
        writeTime(ctx,100,hrPer);
        writeTime(ctx,120,minPer);
        writeTime(ctx,140,secPer);
        
        ctx.restore();
    }
    
    // draws arcs and sets color based on percentages
    function writeTime(ctx,radius,per){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.strokeStyle = calculateColor(per);
        ctx.beginPath();
        partialCircle(ctx,0,0,radius,per);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();  
    }   
    
    // turns a percentage into an RGB color string
    function calculateColor(per){
        var brightness = 255;
        var red = 0;
        var green = 0;
        var blue = 0;
        
        blue = per * brightness;
        green = brightness - blue;
        
        result = 'rgba('+ Math.round(red) + ',' + Math.round(green) + ',' + Math.round(blue) + ',1)';
        return result;
    }
    
    // helper function for partial circles          
    function partialCircle(ctx,x,y,rad,percentage){
        ctx.arc(x,y,rad,0,percentage*(Math.PI*2),false);
        return ctx;
    }
    
    // call the function repeatedly. 66 is the equivalent of about 15 frames per second
    // this seemed enough to make the animation look smooth look without overdoing it.
    setInterval(clock,66);
```

```html
<p><canvas id="clockCanvas" height="600" width="800" style="border:1px solid blue;"></canvas></p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a quick way to draw an arrowhead along an arc:**

1. Use trigonometry to calculate the [x,y] of your arrowhead,
2. `context.translate` to that x,y,
3. `context.rotate` to the current angle of the polar clock,
4. Use path drawing commands to draw your arrow.

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var cx=150;
var cy=150;
var radius=100;
var angle=0;

requestAnimationFrame(animation);


function drawArrow(cx,cy,radius,radianAngle){
  var x=cx+radius*Math.cos(radianAngle);
  var y=cy+radius*Math.sin(radianAngle);
  ctx.translate(x,y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-10,-10);
  ctx.lineTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(10,-10);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}

function animation(time){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  drawArrow(cx,cy,radius,angle);
  angle+=(Math.PI/120);
  requestAnimationFrame(animation);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```